# ffmpeg not generating palettes

Tags: ffmpeg

I downloaded ffmpeg and ran the command found in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen-1) to generate palettes:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf palettegen palette.png`

The only difference being my input was `input.mp4` instead of `input.mkv`.

No file gets generated. Here's the console output from PowerShell:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers  
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2018-11-23T23:27:38.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:09.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2784 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 580x328 [SAR 1:1 DAR 145:82], 2699 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-11-23T23:27:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 79 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-11-23T23:27:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to 'palette.png':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: png, rgba, 16x16 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-11-23T23:27:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 png
[Parsed_palettegen_0 @ 00000296510def00] 255(+1) colors generated out of 285516 colors; ratio=0.000893
[Parsed_palettegen_0 @ 00000296510def00] Dupped color: FF000001
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have this tagged as PowerShell, but you are not using PowerShell to do any of this, well, you are not showing any PowerShell code. Though I assume you are running this from the PowerShell consolehost, vs cmd.exe, that does not make it a PowerShell issue. You are only using the .exe you downloaded. Since this Q&A is all about helping with PowerShell code, this is really off topic. So, I'd suggest moving this to SuperUser or StackExchange, unless you can show your PowerShell code and the PowerShell errors. What you are showing are the .exe errors.

Comment: Thanks, removed that tag

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out that I had two versions of ffmpeg installed and the first one inside of Path was quite outdated. So I removed the older one and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for leaving the solution! This helped me! Just did "where ffmpeg" to find with path I needed to remove from my system environment. Than had to close and reopen cmd to reload the new system environment.